# Returning a writeable to HTTP response

Tags: json, scala, http, playframework, playframework-2.0

I'm returning a JSON to http response, but i'm running into this.

Cannot write an instance of Seq[play.api.libs.json.JsValue] to HTTP response. Try to define a Writeable[Seq[play.api.libs.json.JsValue]]

How do i fix this error?

Comment: It should work. Where do you see this error? Is it displayed in IDE? Or is it in browser? Did you try compile with sbt directly? (sbt compile). Can you show whole source?